# Can't autowire repository in specific service class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, autowired

For some unknown reason after writing some piece of new code I can't autowire repository which cause `NullPointerException`. Everything had worked just fine but out of nowhere that just stopped. I haven't been able to solve this problem since.

The important thing is autowired stopped working in this specific service class, other than there it works just fine.

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class AccountController {

    /**
     *  Display account page based on given module and action. 
     * 
     * @param aModule Account module
     * @param aAction Module action
     * @param principal Logged user
     * @return ModelAndView instance with required objects
     * @throws podraza.piotr.eshopper.exception.NotFoundException
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/{module}/{action}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayAccount(
            final @PathVariable("module") String aModule, 
            final @PathVariable("action") String aAction,
            final Principal principal) throws NotFoundException {

        if(aModule == null || aAction == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        final Module module;
        final Action action;

        try {
            module = Module.valueOf(aModule.toUpperCase());
            action = Action.valueOf(aAction.toUpperCase());
        } catch(RuntimeException ex) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        switch(module) {
            case USER:
                throw new NotFoundException();
            case ITEMS:
                switch(action) {
                    case NEW:
                        return prepareItemNew();
                    case MANAGER:
                        return prepareItemManager();
                    default:
                        throw new NotFoundException();
                }
            case SHOPPING:
                switch(action) {
                    case BIDS:
                        return prepareShoppingBids(principal);
                    default:
                        throw new NotFoundException();
                }
            default:
               throw new NotFoundException();
        }

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws UserNotFoundException 
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/account", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String displayShoppingBids() throws UserNotFoundException {
        return "redirect:/account/shopping/bids";
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param form
     * @param result
     * @param request
     * @param errors
     * @param session
     * @param principal
     * @return 
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/item/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processCreatingNewItem(
            final @ModelAttribute("newItemForm") @Validated NewItemForm form,
            final BindingResult result, 
            final WebRequest request, 
            final Errors errors, 
            final HttpSession session,
            final Principal principal) {

        LOGGER.debug("Proccessing creating new item. Given form: " + form);

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/account/items/manager");

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            Set errorCodes = new HashSet();

            for(ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors()) {
                errorCodes.add(error.getCode());
            }

            mv.addObject("errorCodes", errorCodes);
            mv.setViewName("account-items-new");

            return mv;
        }

        accountService.addNewItem(form, principal);

        return mv;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare ModelAndView instance with containing required objects
     * to perform action of adding new item. 
     * @return ModelAndView instance with required models.
     */
    private ModelAndView prepareItemNew() {
        return new ModelAndView("account-items-new")
                .addObject("newItemForm", new NewItemForm())
                .addObject("formCategories", accountService.getCategoriesForNewItemForm());
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return 
     */
    private ModelAndView prepareItemManager() {
        return new ModelAndView("account-items-manager");
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param principal
     * @return
     * @throws UserNotFoundException 
     */
    private ModelAndView prepareShoppingBids(final Principal principal) throws UserNotFoundException {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("account-shopping-bids");
        mv.addObject("bids", accountService.getUserBids(principal.getName()));
        return mv;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private enum Module {

        USER, 
        ITEMS, 
        SHOPPING

    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private enum Action {

        MESSAGES, 
        SUBSCRIPTIONS, 
        PASSWORD, 
        NEW, 
        MANAGER,
        BIDS

    }

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AccountController.class);

}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class AccountService {

    /**
     * 
     * @param username
     * @return 
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public final List<BidDto> getUserBids(final String username) {
        LOGGER.debug("Fetching bids for user: " + username);

        final User user = userRepository.findByAccountLogin(username);
        final List<Bid> userBids = user.getBids();

        return prepareUserBids(userBids);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return 
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public final List<Category> getCategoriesForNewItemForm() {
        return categoryRepository.findCategoriesWithoutParent();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param form
     * @param principal 
     */
    public final void addNewItem(final NewItemForm form, final Principal principal) {
        final Auction auction = auctionConverter.convertToEntity(form);
        final Item item = auction.getItem();
        final User owner = userRepository.findByAccountLogin(principal.getName());
        item.setOwner(owner);
        itemRepository.save(item);
    }

    /**
     * Convert entity bid objects into DTOs and shorten auction names.
     * @param bids
     * @return 
     */
    private List<BidDto> prepareUserBids(final List<Bid> bids) {
        final List<BidDto> bidsDto = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Bid bid : bids) {
            BidDto bidDto = bidConverter.convertToDto(bid);
            String auctionName = bidDto.getAuction().getName();
            if(auctionName.length() > BIDS_AUCTION_MAX_LENGTH) {
                String shortenName = auctionName.substring(0, BIDS_AUCTION_MAX_LENGTH) + "...";
                bidDto.getAuction().setName(shortenName);
            }
            bidsDto.add(bidDto);
        }
        return bidsDto;
    } 

    private static final int BIDS_AUCTION_MAX_LENGTH = 25; 

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AccountService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BidConverter bidConverter;

    @Autowired
    private AuctionConverter auctionConverter;

}
```

Neither `UserReporitory` nor `CategoryRepository` is getting autowired and both throws `NullPointerException`.

Repositories:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    public User findByAccountLogin(final String login);

    public User findByAccountLoginOrAccountEmail(final String login, final String email);

    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE UPPER(u.account.login) LIKE UPPER('%'||:phrase||'%')")
    public List<User> findUsersByPhrase(final @Param("phrase") String phrase);

}


@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {

    /**
     * Looking for categories with that has no subcategories.
     * @return list of categories
     */
    @Query("SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE parent_id IS NULL ORDER BY c.id")
    public List<Category> findMainCategories();

    /**
     * Looking for categories with given url value.
     * @param url
     * @return Category with given name
     */
    public Category findByUrl(final String url);

    /**
     * Looking for categories without parent category.
     * @return 
     */
    @Query("SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL")
    public List<Category> findCategoriesWithoutParent();

    public Category findByName(final String name);

}
```

Stack trace:

```
2016-02-09 19:33:00 ERROR GlobalExceptionHandlerController:72 - java.lang.NullPointerException
    at podraza.piotr.eshopper.service.AccountService.getUserBids(AccountService.java:61)
    at podraza.piotr.eshopper.web.controller.AccountController.prepareShoppingBids(AccountController.java:169)
    at podraza.piotr.eshopper.web.controller.AccountController.displayAccount(AccountController.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: null
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas what could've caused this problem? I'd be happy to provide any further information if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide the class where you're *calling* `AccountService`.

Comment: Done. `AccountController` added.

Comment: Please also include the entire stack trace, not just the exception class, and indicate which line the exception is being thrown from.

Comment: I have posted stack trace. The exception being thrown any time I try to use any repository instance inside the service class since it's null.

Comment: Can you post your configuration classes/XML as well?  It's possible that the controller and repositories are in two different contexts.

Comment: @woemler That won't be the issue. There's something fishy here, because if Spring fails to autowire a class, it'll throw an exception, not leave a dependency null.

Comment: Which line is 62? Are you *certain* it isn't `final List<Bid> userBids = user.getBids();`?

Comment: @woemler That is not the issue - in any other service class repositories are being autowired and work fine. Even this particular service class had worked before and then something happened that caused the trouble.

Comment: @chrylis It's repository for sure - I've debugged it. Exactly the same happens for this line: `return categoryRepository.findCategoriesWithoutParent();` - `categoryRepository` is null.

Comment: @chrylis What's weird and important - this repositories work perfectly well in EVERY other service class. It's just this particular service that doesn't autowire them.

Comment: I suspect there's a mismatch between the code you posted and the code that is actually running. I'm going to request that in the service class you replace all of the field injection with constructor injection and then see if you get any compilation errors.

Comment: @chrylis I've found the issue... The problem was caused by declaring methods `final`.  Any idea why this caused the trouble? I'm clueless.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Spring can't proxy methods (to apply your `@Transactional` advice) if they're final. This is one advantage of using an interface; Spring can create a JDK proxy that forwards to your implementation class.

Comment: @chrylis It's easy to miss out. Nevertheless thanks for the time you spent on my code trying to find the solution and obviously for valuable knowledge. Really appreciate it.